# adding a .client suffix to my .jsx or .tsx file breaks the import in Remix

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, remix.run

I'm ultimately trying to get remix-utils to help me render a client-side-only component. Was lead to believe that a .client.tsx or .client.jsx file would help (even though I can't find it in the docs anywhere)

So I have this file:

```
// app/components/Test.client.jsx
export default function Test() {
  return <div>This is a test</div>;
}
```

being imported into my index.tsx file:

```
// app/routes/index.tsx
import Test from "~/components/Test.client";

export default function Index() {
  return (
    <div style={{ fontFamily: "system-ui, sans-serif", lineHeight: "1.4" }}>
      <h1>Welcome to Remix</h1>
      <Test />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Why won't this work? I've done this exact setup in a vanilla TypeScript app, and it works fine. Also, if I just remove the .client suffix it will import fine, but adding .client at the end of the file name somehow breaks the app and produces this error:

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Answer (score 3):

The `.client` suffix tells Remix to only include this in the client bundle.

Remember that Remix will render your route component on both the server and the client. By making `Test` a client-only component, it breaks if your route is server rendered (`Test` is essentially `undefined` on the server).

If the component is truly client only, then you also need to use the `<ClientOnly/>` wrapper from remix utils.

```
<ClientOnly>
  {() => <Test/>}
</ClientOnly>
```

This ensures that Remix does not try to render the component server-side.

Comment: The only issue is ClientOnly breaks in v2..

Comment: Hmm... it's working for me. What error are you seeing?

Comment: It was throwing all sorts of errors, I've just decided to make the component SSR..

Comment: @Kiliman the problem is that the error occurs at import, not at rendering, so ClientOnly does not work.